# Remove warning from vim editor for line length exceeding 80 chars

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, spf13vim

I am using [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) plugin for my vim editor.

Whenever I write python code, and if the line length exceeds 80 chars, then it shows me warning in a new horizontal split.

Something like this (see bottom part):

[image]

I want to remove the warning or at-least increase the column char limit (so that I don't get warning very often), but I don't know how to?

I have seen my `.vimrc` file located at `home/username` dir. But the file doesn't contain anything relevant to `column size` or `column limit`.

[here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amit-upadhyay-IT/.vimrc-file/master/spf_vimrc.vimrc) is my `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by Syntastic, or rather `pycodestyle`, which Syntastic uses.

You can [configure pycodestyle](http://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration) to no longer report this error. Simply add E501 to the ignored list in your `.pycodestyle`.

Comment: it worked like magic :), any idea how do they (`pycodestyle`) do this)?

Comment: How they do what? Put the warnings in your quickfix list? That's not `pycodestyle`s, work, it's [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic).